# Semantically display BC/BCE time in HTML5

Tags: html, semantic-web, semantic-markup

I am looking for a solution to semantically represent dates in HTML5. According to the [new specifications](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-time-element) now it is possible to give a date without the day, month part etc like:

```
<time datetime="2011">Last year</time>
```

[This article](http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2012/best-of-time/) also demonstrates some useful examples. But still there is no mention of dates in BC/BCE period. Any semantic solution?

Answer (score 2):

The `time` element is not intended to be used for dates that can not be represented on the [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar), so the `datetime` attribute has no support or standard for years BCE. This seems to be a purposeful limitation due to complications in both `datetime` browser support and adoption of the Gregorian calendar.

Comment: Yes but is there any other solution other than `time` element? Thats my question

Comment: See [Proleptic Gregorian Calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar) for ISO 8601's way of handling this. Expecting all browsers to consistently handle this would perhaps be asking too much, but it's still sad to see it outlawed from HTML.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5, as currently specified, does not allow for dates before the year 0.

The HTML5 datetime format is a subset of the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) datetime format. ISO 8601 allows dates BC/BCE, written simply with a minus prefix, e.g. `-86`.

But in HTML5, the minus prefix is not allowed. I don't know if this is intentional, or what the justification is.

One possible way to deal with this is to simply use ISO 8601 dates with the time element, ignoring HTML5's prohibition of negative values, I guess.

If you care deeply about this, you may also want to file a comment against the HTML spec.

Comment: So you mean to say is that to represent a date example June 20 BCE I should write `<time datetime="-20-06">June 20 BCE</time>` ?